# is there a way my html/css web page can be resized correctly automatically?

Tags: html, css

I made a login screen for website class term project due soon. It looks nice and everything, but when i resize the browser, the whole page just crumbles. Lol, everything just overlaps each other.

Is there a way to fix that? And yes, i already have my CSS in percentages, few pixels here and there, but 99% of my CSS is %.

Also, i already have div sections, which include the login form etc...

But even with those two (as those things are most suggested from my research) the page is still not doing well when resizing the browser to a smaller size. It seems to only work with whatever this current screen i fixed the sizes to be is.

In fact, i took the code home from work, loaded it on my laptop, and even with full browser (not resized), a little aspects here and there were overlapping each other.

If that's the case, i would be worried when we have to present at the end of semester and everything will be messed up on different resolution! :(

Thnx in advance

Comment: You need to use media queries to format your page to different device widths

Comment: I assume you are using a lot of absolute (or fixed) positioning. My recommendation would be to study up on responsive design. You can even look at other login pages, to see how they were created, then use the same principals on your project. Good Luck!

Comment: To be of real help you need to post more code to go along with your question. Also, do you happen to know the concept of 'mobile first development'? It is a concept that revolves around making websites (and other apps) by thinking of this resizing functionality first. Have a look here: https://getflywheel.com/layout/start-practicing-mobile-first-development/

Comment: Learn bootstrap css in order to do responsive design

Comment: @Selva NOOOOOOO!!! Bootstrap is 100% **not** needed. I have made hundreds of responsive sites, and have never touched bootstrap.

Comment: @JacobGray it's true that you can do that without ever hearding the notion of Bootstrap, but for many developers unaware of responsive design, bootstrap can provide a very powerful way to learn and apply responsiveness to their sites. Also keep in mind it can be powerful if used correctly.

Comment: @AGE Right, he's not saying it can't be a useful tool, but Selva's comment made it sound like responsive design was centric around bootstrap. Understanding the concept of what makes bootstrap a useful tool in responsive development is a far better long term idea.

Comment: If the OP is open to using `flexbox`, a simple login form is really easy: http://jsfiddle.net/7dx9h6yp/ (made that in a couple minutes)

Comment: Indeed, it is important to know that you can code a solid responsive site yourself, it can be much lighter in terms of having all the code bootstrap provides when you are only using 10% of it

Comment: If I had to venture a guess, I'd say he could put a container around his content and set a `min-width`. I'm thinking the issue lies in wrapping of elements and fonts.

Comment: Stick everything inside `<div style='float:left'>` container divs and forget about trying to position it.

Comment: @freedomn-m why would i try to float everything left when i used positioning just so that things are exactly where i want them to be (i.e. in the center of the login box that i also have in the center of the full page)?

Comment: @tymeJV someone else as well suggested that here, and i followed the article but i dont think i have time to do a size for every single media device condition out there. i want this to be done automatically. and i am thinking if there is a way to doing that with just simple inserting a small snippet of code. i dont have time to just stay doing login sizes with other pages i have to do for the full website.

Comment: @Chad more details please? o:

Comment: @JacobGray wow, thats quite a nice fancy website to do stuff on. i wish i knew about that before i already did my login page and spent 5 days on it lol. i was using notepad++.

Comment: @AGE i dont really know of the mobile first development. i did read now something about designing for mobile first then expanding it later to the bigger devices. although, thats not gonna help my case here cause ive already finished the login screen here, and ill be forced in class to keep it sized fully :( and if the professor tests it on smaller aspect ration, i'd be screwed! lol

Comment: @goldensunplayer so basically what I'm thinking is that you could wrap your content is a container element, and stop it from going below a certain size. So if you look at this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/q6nctbjz/1/, and resize the preview window, you'll see that the first example will wrap when the window gets too small, whereas the second example will prevent the element from becoming too small to house its children. Essentially you just have to either design for smaller screens or prevent the screen from becoming too small.

Comment: so guys, im seeing bootstrap, then nooo dont use bootstrap. i dont have time to learn or retry anything new, and as of now only familiar with HTML/CSS. (a little JS). i just want a simple fast way that i could do quickly now (like small snippet of code) that would reszie my web page automatically when its resized.

Comment: @Chad thnx for that. i think i already have it wrapped. 

CSS:

.loginPage {
 background: url(../images/FormBackgroundImage.png) no-repeat 100% 0%;
 background-size: cover;
 width:37%;
 margin:9% auto 4% auto;
  position: relative;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}

HTML:
<div class="loginPage">
..........................
some code........
</div>

Comment: please add code snippets as an edit to your original post, describe what this edit is too so that it is both relevant and to you, those who seek to help and the future people who might find your question useful

Comment: @goldensunplayer why use floats?  For the exact reason that you stated: when you resize the screen it will handle it for you.  You only float the containers, so your login inputs still fit in the same place within the login container.  If you wanted centre (then say so...) then use `margin:auto`.  done.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried thr `viewport` meta ? http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

> The viewport is the user's visible area of a web page. The viewport varies with the device, and will be smaller on a mobile phone than on a computer screen.

And this is the best (in my cases) rules for viewport on PC/Tablet/Mobile :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
```

Here, I set the HTML with is the device screen Width, I disabled the zoom content function with `user-scalable=no` and I set the ratio on x and y axes to 1.

Answer (score 0):

What you have essentially asked for in your question is with regards to *media queries and responsive development*

To make a possible long explanation short and sweet: have a read at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), it should have as much material as you will ever need on this subject. Also go to your favorite search engine and look into what mobile first web development is and how you can implement it yourself without the need for a framework like *Bootstrap*, which can be potentially more beneficial to your knowledge and future in web development than anything else.

Things of interest in this subject:

1. [CSS and Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).
2. [SaaS and Media Queries](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-in-sass-using-media-queries-in-sass-32).

It goes without saying that Bootstrap uses media queries for responsive, mobile first web development but it provides this functionality for you rather than you coming up with it... powerful in the right hands.

Best of luck!

Comment: ive read on those media queries, but i dont think i have time to be testing and making different measurements for each device change avialable out there. i am interested now in just applying something to what i already have, liek a snippet of code that i'd insert, and it takes care of resizing automatically the values.

Answer (score 0):

ok guys so i used the following in my CSS sheet in the loginPage div class: min-width: 500px;

and it is much more satisfying than how it was when i was resizing! :D

it now simply keeps the form as is but gets "wrapped"? or like gets eaten from the edges as you cover the webapge smallering it. i am not sure if thats good descriptive enough, but im not sure if thats what you call erapping if you understand what i mean.

i was hoping however that the login form itself could possibly reszie to a smaller size, along with everything (images, elements, etc..) in it, buut alas...if that only simple quick solution here now is to use that min-width for a "better" fix of not overlap whatsoever, then so be it.

if any of you still has some quick short code snippet suggestions for me, that would actually result in my desired solution, i'd welcome to try it gladly.

thnx eveyone for your suggestions

Comment: All you need to do is edit your initial post and add code snippets to the code you're working with that wish to get helped on. To be asked to provide code snippets is too broad because the implementations are just as broad. Keep in mind that you are playing with elements and you need to understand how the elements respond to re-sizeable behavior. A CSS snippet I can give you to apply to a <div> element with content in it is: position: relative; max-width: 100%; min-width: 320px, width: 100%;

Comment: i cant post it unfortunately for professor reasons :[

its alright though, i tried your snippet, and 320 px causes an issue with my form. i just kep it at 500px, and it yield me the same result as simply using just min-width: 500px. 
i also already had the position set to relative